# I'm trying to prevent duplicate email response in google sheets when I run response command

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, email, google-apps-script-editor

I got this code from the Google Sheets tutorial and it works, I want to send an email response after my peers fill out a google form. The email works, so the first step is complete, but it continues to send an email even though I have assigned it not send duplicate emails. My sheet is as follows:

```
    Time Stamp/Email Address/Message/Complete for columns A-D
    date-time/test@email.com/   Test1/  EMAIL_SENT
    date-time/ test@email.com/  Test2/  EMAIL_SENT
    date-time/test@email.com/   Test3/  EMAIL_SENT
```

```js
    // This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
    // has been sent successfully.
    var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

    /**
     * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
     */
    function sendEmails2() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 3; // Number of rows to process
      // Fetch the range of cells B1:D3
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[1]; // Second column
        var message = row[2]; // Third column
        var emailSent = row[3]; // Fourth column
        if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
          var subject = 'Your PFB Request';
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
          sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
          // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);`

`getRange` is not a zero-based method. Your definition defines a range that is only 3 columns wide. It does NOT include the "Complete" column.

Change this to :
`var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4);`

The "Complete" column will equate to row[3] (on a zero-based basis). Currently row[3] has no value, probably "undefined", and would explain why the "IF" statement is not working.

Comment: That was it! reference moved from 3rd column to 4th. Thank you